# Using date_add with a column as interval value and comparing dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, dateadd

I have this employee table:

```
Name        birth_date  retirement_age
Andy        1964-03-13              56
Bertha      1964-11-16              55
Chris       1964-03-08              58
Damon       1964-04-11              56
```

I'm trying to figure out which employee retires this month (November 2019) by adding retirement_age to their birth_date using date_add(). 
The retirement date is always at the end of the month.

This is what I've been working on:

```
SELECT Name,
@ra:=CAST(retirement_age AS UNSIGNED),
LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(`birth_date`, INTERVAL @ra year)) as `retirement_date`, 
FROM `employees`
HAVING
`retirement_date`='2019-11-30'
```

The problem is that the query produces 0 result where it should've returned 1 result (Bertha).
I don't get what's wrong with it.

Can somebody help or maybe recommend me the correct way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using Having instead of Where?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variable `@ra` for which it is not guaranteed that it will be calculated before the column `retirement_date` or `CAST(retirement_age AS UNSIGNED)` directly.
So drop it and use `retirement_age`:

```
SELECT Name,
  LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(`birth_date`, INTERVAL retirement_age year)) AS `retirement_date`
FROM `employees`
HAVING `retirement_date` = '2019-11-30'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qDEFNVTUBR9xGEgTGKA1gE/3).